# Monitor multiple Jenkins servers health checks in a single Jenkins Server as Dashboard?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to monitor multiple Jenkins servers health checks in a single Jenkins server as dashboard.Can some one let me know what all the options do we have for this ??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for managing multiple Jenkins servers health checks in a single Jenkins Server specially on Open source Jenkins. But we can find some similar thing on CloudBees Jenkins where we can integrate Multiple masters together.

CloudBees Jenkins Analytics also make the monitoring of multiple masters easier by adding a number of new graphs.
Please refer the link :  https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/jenkins-operations-and-continuous-delivery-scale-cloudbees-jenkins-enterprise

Comment: However if you want to make that possible on opensource, I believe you need to write a script mentioning that it should login to every server and build the configured health check job and post that on to the Jenkins server which we want to use as Monitoring server.